# How to manipulate a data grid view from another form in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

i know this may be a super asked question but i could not find how to do this, maybe i'm just too dumb, but anyways...

I have a form called frmVendors and a second one called frmAddVendors, in frmVendors i have a data grid view that displays all the information of vendors that i have in my data base and in that form i have a button that shows frmAddVendors, when i add a vendor in frmAddVendors i want to insert that vendor in the data base (i know how to do this) and then "refresh" the data grid view from frmVendors to display the new vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to frmVendors in your main module, and when you add one, call `frmVendors.myGrid.Refresh()`. Let me know if syntax needs fixing, but that's the idea.